# DjangoListField() vs graphene.List() in Graphene Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphql, graphene-django

I used both **"DjangoListField()"** and **"graphene.List()"** with **the Resolver to list all objects**.

**"DjangoListField()" in schema.py:**

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django import DjangoListField
from .models import Category

class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id","name")

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    all_categories = DjangoListField(CategoryType) # DjangoListField()

    def resolve_all_categories(root, info): # Resolver to list all objects
        return Category.objects.all()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

**"graphene.List()" in schema.py:**

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Category

class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id","name")

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    all_categories = graphene.List(CategoryType) # graphene.List()

    def resolve_all_categories(root, info): # Resolver to list all objects
        return Category.objects.all()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Then, I queried **"allCategories"** for **both code in schema.py** above one by one:

```js
query {
  allCategories {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

But the result is the same **to list all objects**:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "allCategories": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "category1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "category2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the difference between **"DjangoListField()"** and **"graphene.List()"**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"DjangoListField()"** has **the Default Resolver to list all objects** but **"graphene.List()"** doesn't have it so for **"graphene.List()"**, you need to **explicitly define the Resolver to list all objects** otherwise you get **"null"**.

So, if you remove **Resolver** from your code with **"DjangoListField()"**:

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django import DjangoListField
from .models import Category

class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id","name")

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    all_categories = DjangoListField(CategoryType) # DjangoListField()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Then, you query **"allCategories"**:

```js
query {
  allCategories {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Finally, you can still **list all objects**:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "allCategories": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "category1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "category2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, if you remove **Resolver** from your code with **"graphene.List()"**:

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Category

class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id","name")

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    all_categories = graphene.List(CategoryType) # graphene.List()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Then, you query **"allCategories"**:

```js
query {
  allCategories {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Finally, you cannot **list all objects** instead you get **"null"**:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "allCategories": null
  }
}
```

You can get more detail about **"DjangoListField()"** in this page [DjangoListField](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/fields/#djangolistfield).